# Zip files in a directory use part of URL as file name

Tags: php, zip

I use a php file to created zip archive of all jpg files in a folder and make it available for download.

Here is the script:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$download = 'FileName.zip';
$zip->open($download, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $file) { /* Add appropriate path to read content of zip */
    $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = $download");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($download));
header("Location: $download");
?>
```

I was wondering if it is possible to use part of url as archive name?
My URLS look like this:

```
https://www.example.com/data/pictures/album/
```

I want the archive name to be `Pictures-Album-CustomText.zip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

Option 1: Using a combination of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, `substr()`, and `str_replace()`.

Option 2: Using a combination of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, `rtrim()`, `explode()`, and `count()`.

1st option, broken down:

---

```
$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];              // the current full url
strrpos($url, "pictures/")                // finds "pictures/" in the $url variable
substr($url, strrpos($url, "pictures/"))  // extracts everything from "pictures/" onwards
str_replace("/","-", $name_pre);          // replaces "/" with "-"
```

---

```
<?php

    $url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $name_pre = substr($url, strrpos($url, "pictures/"));
    $name_pre = str_replace("/","-", $name_pre);
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $download = $name_pre . 'FileName.zip';
    $zip->open($download, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $file) { 
       $zip->addFile($file);
    }
    $zip->close();
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = $download");
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($download));
    header("Location: $download");
?>
```

---

2nd option, broken down:

```
$url = rtrim($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], "/"); // get url and remove trailing "/"
$url_pieces = explode('/', $url);        // break string into pieces based on "/"
$url_pieces_count = count($url_pieces);  // count the number of pieces
$name_pre = $url_pieces[($url_pieces_count - 2)] . "-" . $url_pieces[($url_pieces_count - 1)] . "-"; // construct the filename preface
```

---

```
<?php

    $url = rtrim("https://www.example.com/data/pictures/album/", "/");
    $url_pieces = explode('/', $url);
    $url_pieces_count = count($url_pieces);
    $name_pre = $url_pieces[($url_pieces_count - 2)] . "-" . $url_pieces[($url_pieces_count - 1)] . "-";
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $download = $name_pre . 'FileName.zip';
    $zip->open($download, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $file) { 
       $zip->addFile($file);
    }
    $zip->close();
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = $download");
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($download));
    header("Location: $download");
?>
```

Comment: Great this works however the filename is not as i expected. File name becomes the entire URL part after .com "-data-pictures-album-download.phpFileName.zip" What i want is last two part of URL "Pictures-Album-FileName.zip" I believe I need to do some trimming and change case to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: I've defined the `$name_pre` variable twice to clearly show what is happening in the code. You don't have to break it down like that.

Comment: Thanks @Mech it worked with just a minor modification I post the final code here. Please let me know if the code can be improved?

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

This becomes my final code (@Mech code + ucwods) i used ucwords to capatilize words after -

```
<?php

$url = rtrim($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], "/"); // get url and remove trailing "/"
$url_pieces = explode('/', $url);
$url_pieces_count = count($url_pieces);
$name_pre = $url_pieces[($url_pieces_count - 3)] . "-" . $url_pieces[($url_pieces_count - 2)] . "-";
$name_final = ucwords($name_pre, "-");
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$download = $name_final . 'FileName.zip';
$zip->open($download, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $file) { 
   $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = $download");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($download));
header("Location: $download");
?>
```